# How does format string {0:d MMM YYYY} work?

Tags: c#

My code is pretty simple in razor view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Customer.Birthdate,"{0:d MMMM YYYY}")
```

this format string convert `m.Customer.Birthdate` into `1 Jan, 1980`.

My question is: why **0:** is used before: **d MMMM YYYY** ?

Comment: Try read [Custom Date & Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) - the `{0}` prefix used because it implicitly calls [`string.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2) to first `DateTime` parameter with specified string.

Comment: `0` is index component of the [Format Item Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#format-item-syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0 will be replace by datevalue in the Customer.Birthdate in this format MMMM YYYY
.The {0} would be the placeholder for the first argument. It is simply a format string to convert the first argument to a string.

Answer (score 1):

When you format a String (BTW in many programming languages), you need to tell the formatter where you want to put what.
For example, you have an array with the names of family members.
And you want to create a sentence that includes all of them.
What you can do is:

```
string[] names = new string[] { "dad", "mom", "child" };
String sentence = String.Format("{0} and {1} took the {2} to the doctor",
                   names[0], names[1], names[2]);
```

This way you indicate where you want to put the strings in the formatted string.